# RequiresMountsFor not working on Debian 8

Tags: debian, nfs, systemd, autofs

I am trying to set up a systemd service on Debian 8 to run a program from the network on startup but it does not work - the service starts before mounting NFS disks have completed. I have the following setup:

```
# cat /etc/auto.master | grep -v "#"
+dir:/etc/auto.master.d
+auto.master
/fs-1  /etc/auto.fs-1

# cat /etc/auto.fs-1
shared   -nosuid,nodev   fs-1:/shared

ls -l / | grep shared
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    12 Oct 19 14:33 build -> /fs-1/shared

# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/psr_25.service
[Unit]
Description=PSR 2.5 Server
Wants=network.target network-online.target autofs.target
After=network.target network-online.target autofs.target
RequiresMountsFor=/shared/psr/25/bin

[Service]
Type=forking
User=testuser

ExecStart=/shared/psr/25/bin/server

TimeoutSec=300
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How to make the service start after /shared has mounted?

Comment: Answerers might want to see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246935/ for some hints.

Comment: Isn't it kind of philosophically contradictory to want both filesystems to be mounted only when accessed and at the same time being automatically mounted at start? Why using automounting if they are mounted automatically at each start? I would remove the automounting part and then just create standard `/etc/fstab` entries and let `systemd` mount those at boot.